# You need permission to perform this action. Ubuntu 22.04 / Windows 10 / SMB

Tags: permissions, 22.04, samba, windows-10, fstab

I mounted 2 hds and installed Samba to be able to access them from my Windows computer. When I access the network in Windows, on one of the hds (mounted in /media/Courses) I can create and delete files, on the other (mounted on /media/Fotos) I am able to read files, however, I am not able to create files or delete them, when I try this appears the follow message:

"You need permission to perform this action"

I removed the "+" that was in /media/Fotos permissions by doing:

sudo setfacl -Rbk media
sudo systemctl restart smb

For me the permissions for these 2 hds are identical, I don't understand why I can't delete files in /media/Fotos.

What do I have to do to be able to create and delete files via Windows in /media/Fotos?

Follow the permissions and output of some commands and files:

```
drwxrwxrwx   8 paivadesktop paivadesktop 4096 abr 20 17:03 Cursos/
drwxrwxrwx   6 paivadesktop paivadesktop 4096 abr 20 17:02 Fotos/
```

lsblk

```
sdc      8:32   0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   1,8T  0 part /media/Cursos
sdd      8:48   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0 931,5G  0 part /media/Fotos
```

getfacl Fotos

```
# file: Fotos
# owner: paivadesktop
# group: paivadesktop
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

getfacl Cursos

```
# file: Cursos
# owner: paivadesktop
# group: paivadesktop
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

sudo nano /etc/fstab

```
# Fotos (/dev/sdc1) (1TB)
UUID=965cca97-3409-49a4-a559-1a52200b3cae       /media/Fotos   ext4    defaults        0       0

# Cursos (/dev/sdb1) (2TB)
UUID=051df214-7ef5-4201-bf5f-554c276b6429       /media/Cursos   ext4    defaults        0       0
```

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[Fotos]
   path = /media/Fotos
   read only = no
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700

[Cursos]
   path = /media/Cursos
   read only = no
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
```